# Match any number and any word in any order

Tags: php, regex, cakephp

i'be trying to make a regular expression in cakephp to match the following :

the following should match : 
*phone* could be any word

2014 phone
phone 2014

but, these should not match:

2014
2014phone
phone2014

Comment: `(2014 \w+|\w+ 2014)`?

Comment: Is this a literal `2014 ` or could it be some other number/boundary?

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for an implicit year use:

```
(\w+)\s(\d{1,4})|(\d{1,4})\s(\w+)
```

There is likely a cleaner of doing this witih lookbacks/lookaheads, but I've convinced myself those are greedy (+CPU usage).

- `\w+` will give you any word without a space in it
- `\s` will give you a space
- `\d{1,4}` will give you repeating digits between 1 and 4 placeholders
- `|` is just an "or" operator